# How do I use Stagefright from the command line?

Tags: android, stagefright

How do I use Stagefright from the command line?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, stagefright can be used from a command line if you have rooted your device and can access a command line. Here's output from my android board:

```
root@android:/ # stagefright -h                                                
usage: stagefright
       -h(elp)
       -a(udio)
       -n repetitions
       -l(ist) components
       -m max-number-of-frames-to-decode in each pass
       -b bug to reproduce
       -p(rofiles) dump decoder profiles supported
       -t(humbnail) extract video thumbnail or album art
       -s(oftware) prefer software codec
       -r(hardware) force to use hardware codec
       -o playback audio
       -w(rite) filename (write to .mp4 file)
       -k seek test
       -x display a histogram of decoding times/fps (video only)
       -S allocate buffers from a surface
       -T allocate buffers from a surface texture
       -d(ump) filename (raw stream data to a file)
       -D(ump) filename (decoded PCM data to a file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Stagefright is a native library and does not have a command line test app. Still, [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) in android framewrork is easy to use and uses Stagefright under the covers.