# How to install stagefright on my android?

Tags: android, audio, stagefright

I hear about this sound program that supposedly comes with Android called "stagefright" that is needed in order to play audio files from the command-line of a terminal emulator. One source from which I heard of it is here: [How do I use Stagefright from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900692/how-do-i-use-stagefright-from-the-command-line)

Problem is --- I checked pretty well for it on my Android device (Aesus Nexus 7) and it isn't there. (Either there is no "stagefright" or it's command-line interface program is missing.) How can I get it installed --- and if I can't, is there anything *else* I could install that would allow me to play audio files from the terminal-emulator command line?

I ask this because my inability to play audio files from the command-line is a *serious* limitation.

Comment: stagefright will not yield a portable solution.  The proper approach for doing this would be to send an Intent to get the file played by whatever is available on the device.

Comment: So how do I do it from the terminal commend line? All the examples I saw on how to send an intent were on how to do it from Java? A less-than-fully-portable way of solving my problem from the command line can be segregated for portability. On the other hand, a method of doing it through the java API for full-fledged asps is useless for my purpose.

Comment: You can send Intents from the adb command line using the 'am start' command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As android generally reserves direct audio access permission to system processes acting as delegates for applications through Android app-only APIs, a stagefright executable would not be something you could add to a secured device if it was not placed there by the system vendor.  However, you can accomplish your need to play audio upon request from the adb command line by using an Intent.

Here's an example - adjust to your specifics:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///mnt/sdcard/ringtones/hangouts_video_call.ogg -t audio/ogg
```

Remember to change that to audio/mp3 if that is your file type

This utilizes the default player - if doesn't give precisely the behavior you want, you may need to make your own custom player app with that behavior, and then use an Intent (with an explicit package name) to trigger it from the command line.

Comment: Guess next time I'll just leave things with the comment hinting at the path towards a solution, and not bother working out and testing an example...